# Summing Normal random variables

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I would like to plot the graph of the sum of two random variables.So, I wrote

```
Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1]+NormalDistribution[0, 1], x], {x, -10, 10}]
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Also, if you need exactly what you tried to execute you can use `Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x] + 
  PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x], {x, -10, 10}, Filling -> Axis, 
 PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: And also thanks to Szabolcs for the MixtureDistribution command. ;)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Actually I was very stupid and gave you an incorrect answer.  I apologize.  I corrected it now.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for the help. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to use [`TransformedDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TransformedDistribution.html) to achieve this:

```
d = TransformedDistribution[
   a + b, 
   {a \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1], b \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[2, 2]}]

(* ==> NormalDistribution[2, Sqrt[5]] *)
```

This represents the distribution of `a+b` if `a` is distributed according to `NormalDistribution[0, 1]` and `b` is distributed according to `NormalDistribution[2, 2]`.

In this case the result is automatically simplified to another `NormalDistribution`, but it can be used in cases when it can't be automatically simplified as well.

As usual, you can obtain the PDF using `PDF[d, x]`, and then plot it.

Comment: Many thanks Szabolcs. ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can also try

```
Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x] + 
  PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x], {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

so just make each Normal Distribution it's own PDF.

Comment: This is incorrect. The OP wanted the PDF of the sum of two random variables, not the sum of two PDFs.